# Building V8 with Clang/LLVM

Tags: v8

I am building V8 from sources on Windows following this [instruction](https://v8.dev/docs/build).

It works but uses MSVS C++ compiler and I need to switch compilation to Clang/LLVM. It is installed on the machine but I have no idea how to specify it during the build.

I see `is_clang` flag in args.gn but it seems it is true by default.

Any ideas?

From toolchain.ninja file

```
rule cxx
  command = ..\..\third_party\llvm-build\Release+Asserts\bin\clang-cl.exe /c ${in} /Fo${out} /nologo /showIncludes:user "-imsvc../../../../Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.34.31933/include" "-imsvc../../../../Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.34.31933/ATLMFC/include" "-imsvc../../../../Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Auxiliary/VS/include" "-imsvc../../../../Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/include/10.0.20348.0/ucrt" "-imsvc../../../../Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/include/10.0.20348.0/um" "-imsvc../../../../Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/include/10.0.20348.0/shared" "-imsvc../../../../Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/include/10.0.20348.0/winrt" "-imsvc../../../../Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/include/10.0.20348.0/cppwinrt" "-imsvc../../../../Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/NETFXSDK/4.8/include/um" ${defines} ${include_dirs} ${cflags} ${cflags_cc} /Fd"${target_out_dir}/${label_name}_cc.pdb"
  description = CXX ${out}
  deps = msvc
```

Comment: The default build should use Clang, and in fact works well on systems that don't even have MSVS installed. What makes you think it's using the MSVC compiler?

Comment: @jmrk In out/release folder which is created during build I see files related to MSVS like vcruntime140.dll

Comment: You can run `autoninja -v -C out/x64.release d8` (probably after either updating your checkout, or cleaning the output directory, so it doesn't just say "nothing to do") to see what commands it actually executes to invoke the compiler.

Comment: @jmrk I've included related part of toolchain.ninja file, not sure what does it mean. It mentions both clang and msvc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `command = ..\..\third_party\llvm-build\Release+Asserts\bin\clang-cl.exe`

That means it's using Clang to compile. That's its own bundled Clang, so it doesn't need you to manually install Clang on your system.

Comment: Thanks, so it is really used by default and I don't even need to install llvm/clang? Why do I have dlls from MS VC in the output folder?

Comment: @demonplus Re default: yes. Re DLLs: not sure, I guess all Windows binaries need those and the Windows SDK provides them? Similar to how "everything" needs `libc.so` on Linux?